# What does Collections.unmodifiableSet() do in Java?

Tags: java, final, unmodifiable

I can see that [`Collections.unmodifiableSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableSet-java.util.Set-) returns an unmodifiable view of the given set but I don't understand why we can't just use the `final` modifier to accomplish this.

In my understanding, `final` declares a constant: something that cannot be modified. So, if a set is declared as a constant then it cannot be modified: nothing can be removed from the set and nothing can be added.

Why do we need `Collections.unmodifiableSet`?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

`final` declares an object reference that can't be modified, e.g.

```
private final Foo something = new Foo();
```

creates a new `Foo` and places the reference in `something`. Thereafter, it's not possible to alter `something` to point to a different instance of `Foo`.

This does *not* prevent modification of the internal state of the object. I can still call whatever methods on `Foo` there are accessible to the relevant scope. If one or more of those methods modifies the internal state of that object, then `final` won't prevent that.

As such, the following:

```
private final Set<String> fixed = new HashSet<String>();
```

does *not* create a `Set` that can't be added to or otherwise altered; it just means that `fixed` will only ever reference that instance.

By contrast, doing:

```
private Set<String> fixed = Collections.unmodifiableSet( new HashSet<String>() );
```

creates an instance of a `Set` which will throw `UnsupportedOperationException` if one attempts to call `fixed.add()` or `fixed.remove()`, for example - the object itself will protect its internal state and prevent it from being modified.

For completeness sake:

```
private final Set<String> fixed = Collections.unmodifiableSet( new HashSet<String>() );
```

creates an instance of a `Set` which won't allow its internal state to be changed, and also means that `fixed` will only ever point to an instance of that set.

The reason that `final` can be used to create constants of primitives is based on the fact that the value can't be changed. Remember that `fixed` above was just a reference - a variable containing an address that can't be changed. Well, for primitives, e.g.

```
private final int ANSWER = 42;
```

the value of `ANSWER` is that 42. Since `ANSWER` can't be changed, it will only ever have the value 42.

An example that blurs all the lines would be this:

```
private final String QUESTION = "The ultimate question";
```

Per the rules above, `QUESTION` contains the address of an instance of `String` which represents "The ultimate question", and that address can't be changed. The thing to remember here is that `String` itself is immutable - you can't do anything to an instance of `String` which changes it, and any operations which would otherwise do so (such as `replace`, `substring`, etc.) return references to entirely different instances of `String`.

Comment: however, you can create a final reference to an immutable collection containing mutable objects -- if you then change the contained objects, the collection will appear to change...

Comment: To elaborate on @sesquipedalias’s comment: If you have a `final` and unmodifiable `Set<Person>`, you can still alter e.g. the `age` of a `Person` in the set if and only if the `Person` class lets you do this; the `Set` container cannot prevent this, even if it wanted to.

Answer (score 18):

`final` only guarantees that the **reference** to the object the variable represents can't be changed it doesn't do anything for the instance of the object and its mutability.

`final Set s = new Set();` just guarantees you can't do `s = new Set();` again. It doesn't make the set unmodifiable, it if did you couldn't add anything to it to begin with. So to make it really clear, `final` only affects the variable **reference** not the object the reference points to.

I can do the following:

```
final List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
l.add("hello");
l.add("world");
l.remove(0);
```

but I can't do this.

```
l = new ArrayList<String>();
```

again because of the `final` I can't modify what the variable l points to.

you have to do one of the following three things to make a Collection container thread safe.

```
java.util.Collections.syncronizedXXX();
```

or

```
java.util.Collections.unmodifiableXXX();
```

or
use one of the appropriate containers from `java.util.concurrency.* package`.

if I had a `Person` object and did `final Person p = new Person("me");` it means I can't reassign `p` to point to another `Person` object. I can still do `p.setFirstName("you");`

What confuses the situation is that

```
final int PI = 3.14;
final String greeting = "Hello World!";
```

look like `const` in C++, when in fact the objects that they point to are immutable/unmodifiable by nature. Containers or objects with mutator methods that can alter the internal state of the object are not `const` just the **reference** to those objects are `final` and can't be reassigned to **reference** another object.

Comment: Good post. In short, the _reference_ can't be changed but the _contents_ of the object *can*.

Answer (score 4):

The `Collections.unmodifiableSet(Set<? extends T>)` will create wrapper on the original set. This wrapper set can not be modified. but still the original set can be modified.

**Example:**

```
 Set<String> actualSet=new HashSet<String>(); //Creating set
```

Adding some elements

```
actualSet.add("aaa");
actualSet.add("bbb");
```

Printing added elements

```
System.out.println(actualSet);   //[aaa, bbb]
```

Put the `actualSet` into unmodifiable set and assigned to new reference(`wrapperSet`).

```
Set<String> wrapperSet=Collections.unmodifiableSet(orginalSet);
```

Print the wrapperSet. so it will have `actualSet` Values

```
System.out.println(wrapperSet);   //[aaa, bbb]
```

lets try to remove/add one element on `wrapperSet`.

```
wrapperSet.remove("aaa");   //UnSupportedOperationException
```

Add one more element in `actualSet`

```
    actualSet .add("ccc");
```

Print `actualSet` and `wrapperSet`. both sets values are same. so If you add/remove any elements on actual set the changes will be reflected on wrapper set as well.

```
    System.out.println(actualSet);  //[aaa, ccc, bbb]
    System.out.println(wrapperSet);  // [aaa, ccc, bbb]
```

**Usage:**

This  `Collections.unmodifiableSet(Set<? extends T>)` is used to prevent modification of Set's getter method of any object. let say

```
public class Department{

    private Set<User> users=new HashSet<User>();

    public Set<User> getUsers(){
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(users); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`final` is not (C++-style) `const`. Unlike C++, Java does not have `const`-methods or anything like that, and methods that can change the object can be called via a `final` reference.

`Collections.unmodifiable*` is a wrapper that enforces (at run time only, not at compile time) the read-only-ness for the collection concerned.

Answer (score 1):

Summarize that we can do and can't:

Preparation:

```
private Set<String> words = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("existing word"));
```

## Final by reference

```
private final Set<String> words = new HashSet<>();
```

**can**:

```
words.add("new word");
```

**can't**:

```
words = new HashSet<>(); //compilation error
```

## Final by reference and unmodifiable by collection.

private final Set words = Collections.unmodifiableSet(words);

**can**:

```
String word = words.iterator().next();
```

**can't**:

```
words = new HashSet<>(); // compilation error
words.add("new word"); // runtime error UnsupportedOperationException
```

## Final by reference and unmodifiable by collection but mutable as collection's object.

**But** if you have the collection with [mutual](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html) objects you can CHANGE the inner state of that object.

```
 class A {
       public int a; //mutable field. I can change it after initialization
       public A(int a) {this.a = a;}
     }
    
 private final Set<A> set = Collections.unmodifiableSet(Arrays.asList(new A(25)));
```

**Still can't**

```
set = new HashSet<>(); // compilation error
set.add(new A(777)); // runtime error UnsupportedOperationException
```

**But can**

```
 A custom = words.iterator().next(); //here custom.a = 25;
 custom.a = 777; //here first element of **final, unmodifible** collection 
    //was changed from 25 to 777
```